# Extend addProductstoCart mutation in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, graphql

I want to extend the addProductsToCart mutation because I need to pass some product attributes and get the into cart using $_item->getProduct()->getData('attribute_name');

In my custom module, I created the etc/schema.graphqls file with the following configuration ...

`input CartItemInput { attribute_name: String @resolver (class: "\\MyVendor\\MyModule\\Model\\Resolver\\AttributeName") }`

Then, inside the AttributeName.php resolver, I have

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\GetCartForUser;

class AttributeName implements ResolverInterface
{
    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Inside Magento_Checkout, default.phtml, when I try to get this attribute, it doesn't work.

What's the issue?